# Does this word qualify as a word - "evermore-so"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've not seen this used much. Can someone perhaps direct me to a more appropriate word.

Edit: I would like to use it in emphasizing a current situation where something has become abundant over a short period.

Ie:

> Cyberspace is filled with various x, y and evermoreso now the extensive option for z.

Comment: Could you give some context to explain where you'd like to use this?

Comment: I've definitely heard it (as three individual words), but I'm not sure if it's a corruption of "even more so" or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Random House Word Menu](http://www.answers.com/topic/emphasizers-related-word-list), there is actually "evermore so", and it's an emphsizer.

Someone else on his blog wrote [this:](http://dublab.com/learn/reading/one-word-2-evermore-so/)

> and yet I felt evermore-so. ...

Comment: I saw that blog too, but no other source I could find used the same word. However, good find on the Random House link

Answer (score 3):

After searching Google for a while, I was unable to find any real use of the exact phrase "evermore-so" or "evermoreso". That being said, I would suggest a few alternatives:

*"even more so"*:

> Cyberspace is now filled with various widgets, and is *even more so* now the chosen option for fubars.

You can change the descriptor to express the growth differently, such as:

> Cyberspace is now filled with various widgets, and is *increasingly more so* the chosen option for fubars.

Perhaps another member can give a one-word suggestion, but in my mind it's really a phrase.

Comment: I think the meaning that I want is not preserved. My wrong in not expressing it properly.